# Accepting two offers from two EU countries

Tags: employment, european-union, visa

I had an offer from a **Spanish** company last month and I accepted it. And because I am a **non EU citizen** I need Visa process to be completed before I can join I am waiting for some documents here in my country to start Visa application for Spain. Till now nothing is started regarding work permit or Visa in **Spain**.
Due to expected delay in process I am starting the Spanish company as a Freelancer after signing the contract next month. That's half of the situation.

Now I have another offer in **Germany** that I have also accepted and going to sign a contract to start my Visa process for Germany. Remember no process for Visa is started for Spain till now.

Now my question is that is this whole scenario valid? Or will I face any problem?

Because I personally want to join **German** company that's why I am **starting** its Visa process first but I also want to have a back up so I am **starting Spanish** company as a Freelancer with **contract** but **not starting its Visa** process.

Comment: You are not giving enough context. Without knowing the terms of your agreement with the company from Spain it is impossible to assess whether or not you might incur breach of contract. The fact that "till now nothing is started" regarding Spain does not necessarily mean that agreement is voidable by you.

Comment: Basically I have not signed any sort of contract with Spanish company. I have just accepted their offer letter which states that it will be a full time permanent position but in addition to this the offer letter says that: "This letter has no legal affects".

Comment: You're double-dealing with the Spanish company; behaving this way is a form of dishonesty. "No legal effect" doesn't mean no effect. If you end up going with the German company, and the Spanish company finds out about it (and they probably will, they're interested in you and will wonder where you've disappeared to), your reputation may be negatively impacted.

Comment: Seconding @DavidSupportsMonica. If you've received an offer letter, whether or not it has legal effect, and especially if these companies or the divisions within the companies work in the same industry, the potential harm to your reputation doesn't seem worth whatever it is you're trying to do.  You are in a good position, in driver's seat, so to speak, with two offers from presumably two good companies. Pick the one that will suit you best long-term and go with it!

Comment: Seconding @A.fm. If your acceptance of the offer from the German company has been acknowledged by the German company, then move forward with the German company _and tell the Spanish company that you've accepted another offer_.

Answer (score 1):

> is this whole scenario valid?

Yes. This is as valid as the company's right to move forward with multiple candidates simultaneously (without letting you know whatsoever) and see which hiring process is most feasible or convenient. At this point there is no indication that you or the company are subject to some sort of exclusivity, not even from a moral or reputational standpoint (contrary to the suggestion in [this comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52607/accepting-two-offers-from-two-eu-countries?noredirect=1#comment105433_52607)). Thus, there is no reason why you should impose on yourself a unilateral constraint in a context of ambiguity like the one you describe.

The [disclaimer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52607/accepting-two-offers-from-two-eu-countries?noredirect=1#comment105427_52607) that "*This letter has no legal effects*" implies that neither you nor the company from Spain can reasonably expect a commitment from the counterparty. You yourself point out that the visa process has not even started. The company's letter is merely an expression of its interest in your skills set. In this sense it reciprocates your expression of interest (from when you applied for the job), which does not restrict the company's right to eventually decline your application either. Once the company wishes to upgrade to a less ambiguous status, it can start by informing you accordingly and proceed based on your response.

Furthermore, the prolonged uncertainty of both processing and granting of your visa in a country would make it inequitable to preclude you from trying to secure a job elsewhere. The company from Spain can likewise seek arrangements elsewhere to overcome that same uncertainty. Just as a matter of equity, either party ought to inform the counterparty if it decides to rescind the relation or withdraw therefrom.